Lottie animation invisible, but the space of the animation is taken on screen
Why I can't see any animation? I tried with different animations and still same problem I can't see the animation.
Code:
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { NavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from "../../FirebaseConfig";
import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";

interface RouterProps {
  navigation: NavigationProp<any, any>;
}

const Dashboard = ({ navigation }: RouterProps) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Button onPress={() => FIREBASE_AUTH.signOut()} title="Logout" />
      <View>
        <LottieView
          source={require("../../assets/animations/loading2.json")}
          style={{ width: 400, height: 400 }}
          autoPlay
          loop
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;



I copied your codes in mine, and I see no errors, will you please, provide more codes, exactly where you are showing the Dashboard component? Also did you tried the giving flex: 1 to the parent view?

@AnwerSolangi Yeah I tried by giving flex 1
My dashboard is here:
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const InsideStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
function InsideLayout() {
return (
<InsideStack.Navigator>
<InsideStack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
<InsideStack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
</InsideStack.Navigator>
);
}

Do you see the logout button on your screen? If yes, could you please try giving a different color to the View and try with that, I know this might be weird, but, I also encounter a similar issue and in my side the issue was with the theming and colors I was passing to NavigationContainer.

@AnwerSolangi still not working... It's really weird

try removing the View component wrapping the LottieView

@AnwerSolangi does not work yet, I removed the View component.

Strange, could you please confirm if the LottieView animation is working in other components or not? I am a bit sure that there is something wrong with theming part, your codes are working fine
